# Why lerna publish URL econdes a scoped package name triggering ERR! E404 error

Tags: publish, lerna

I'm using `lerna` to automate the publishing of scoped packages in an open source mono repository, [Web User Interface Framework, branch FM-423-lerna](https://github.com/anvil-open-software/wuf), using the `lerna publish` command. This command builds all the packages just fine, but fails with the following messages:

```sh
lerna http fetch PUT 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@anviltech%2fwuf-web-message 393ms
lerna ERR! E404 Not found
```

Notice that it appears that the package name's `slash` was replaced with a `%2f`, leading to an incorrect URL.

I also created a [lerna issue](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2131)

[WUF](https://github.com/anvil-open-software/wuf) is an open source project. Clone it, navigate to its root folder, and execute the following command to observe the failure:

```sh
$ lerna publish from-package --yes --content ./dist
```

Other `lerna` commands, such as `lerna changed` yield the package names correctly:

```sh
$ lerna changed
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v3.13.1
lerna info versioning independent
lerna info Looking for changed packages since v2.0.0-rc.14
@anviltech/wuf-web-assets
@anviltech/wuf-web-code-sample
@anviltech/wuf-web-message
@anviltech/wuf-ang-configuration
@anviltech/wuf-ang-dashboard
@anviltech/wuf-ang-drawer
@anviltech/wuf-ang-gridster
@anviltech/wuf-ang-layout
@anviltech/wuf-ang-login-animated
@anviltech/wuf-ang-navigation
@anviltech/wuf-ang-smart-table
@anviltech/wuf-ang-utils
lerna success found 12 packages ready to publish
```

The same is true for other `lerna` and `yarn` commands, including `yarn publish`.

**Note**: I experimented with [bolt](https://github.com/boltpkg/bolt) and observed the same behavior!

## Expected Behavior

`lerna` does not fail due to the scoped package name change

## Observed Behavior

The `observed` behavior is `lerna` failure to publish packages:

```sh
$ lerna publish from-package --ignore-scripts --yes —skip-git
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v3.13.1
lerna info versioning independent

Found 11 packages to publish:
 - @anviltech/wuf-web-assets => 2.0.0-rc.18.1
 - @anviltech/wuf-web-code-sample => 2.0.0-rc.1.1
 - @anviltech/wuf-web-message => 2.0.0-rc.2.1
 - @anviltech/wuf-ang-dashboard => 2.0.0-rc.2.1
 - @anviltech/wuf-ang-drawer => 2.0.0-rc.3.1
 - @anviltech/wuf-ang-gridster => 2.0.0-rc.1.1
 - @anviltech/wuf-ang-layout => 2.0.0-rc.9.1
 - @anviltech/wuf-ang-login-animated => 2.0.0-rc.3.1
 - @anviltech/wuf-ang-navigation => 2.0.0-rc.8.1
 - @anviltech/wuf-ang-smart-table => 2.0.0-rc.3.1
 - @anviltech/wuf-ang-utils => 2.0.0-rc.1.1

lerna info auto-confirmed
lerna info publish Publishing packages to npm...
lerna info Verifying npm credentials
lerna http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/user 105ms
lerna http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/org/rodrigo.silveira/package?format=cli 98ms
lerna info lifecycle @anviltech/wuf-web-assets@2.0.0-rc.18.1~prepublish: @anviltech/wuf-web-assets@2.0.0-rc.18.1
lerna info lifecycle @anviltech/wuf-web-code-sample@2.0.0-rc.1.1~prepublish: @anviltech/wuf-web-code-sample@2.0.0-rc.1.1
lerna info lifecycle @anviltech/wuf-web-message@2.0.0-rc.2.1~prepublish: @anviltech/wuf-web-message@2.0.0-rc.2.1
lerna info lifecycle @anviltech/wuf-ang-dashboard@2.0.0-rc.2.1~prepublish: @anviltech/wuf-ang-dashboard@2.0.0-rc.2.1
lerna info lifecycle @anviltech/wuf-ang-drawer@2.0.0-rc.3.1~prepublish: @anviltech/wuf-ang-drawer@2.0.0-rc.3.1
lerna info lifecycle @anviltech/wuf-ang-gridster@2.0.0-rc.1.1~prepublish: @anviltech/wuf-ang-gridster@2.0.0-rc.1.1
lerna info lifecycle @anviltech/wuf-ang-navigation@2.0.0-rc.8.1~prepublish: @anviltech/wuf-ang-navigation@2.0.0-rc.8.1
lerna info lifecycle @anviltech/wuf-ang-utils@2.0.0-rc.1.1~prepublish: @anviltech/wuf-ang-utils@2.0.0-rc.1.1

> @anviltech/wuf-web-assets@2.0.0-rc.18.1 prepublish /Users/rodrigosilveira/projects/wuf/packages/wuf-web-assets
> yarn dist:prep && yarn dist:src && yarn dist:pkg

yarn run v1.15.2
$ rm -rf ./dist && mkdir ./dist
✨  Done in 0.13s.
yarn run v1.15.2
$ cp -r ./assets ./dist
✨  Done in 0.12s.
yarn run v1.15.2
$ cp package.json ./dist
✨  Done in 0.15s.

> @anviltech/wuf-web-code-sample@2.0.0-rc.1.1 prepublish /Users/rodrigosilveira/projects/wuf/packages/wuf-web-code-sample
> yarn packagr && cp package.json ./dist

yarn run v1.15.2
$ yarn build
$ webpack
ts-loader: Using typescript@3.2.4 and /Users/rodrigosilveira/projects/wuf/packages/wuf-web-code-sample/tsconfig.json
Hash: 486160bb3bc2f19d293a
Version: webpack 3.12.0
Time: 3134ms
               Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
  wuf-code-sample.js  1.05 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
wuf-code-sample.d.ts  1.23 kB          [emitted]
   [2] ./src/wuf-code-sample.ts 7.48 kB {0} [built]
   [4] ./src/wuf-code-sample.scss 318 bytes {0} [built]
   [5] /Users/rodrigosilveira/projects/wuf/node_modules/css-loader!/Users/rodrigosilveira/projects/wuf/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--2-2!./src/wuf-code-sample.scss 892 bytes {0} [built]
    + 191 hidden modules
✨  Done in 4.70s.

... many other packages built

lerna http fetch PUT 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@anviltech%2fwuf-web-message 393ms
lerna ERR! E404 Not found
```

Answer (score 4):

I found and fixed the problem. Embarrassingly, I was not an organization member! I wish the error message was more clear.

Comment: how did you figure out you were not an org member?